How to reference a parameter with custom link text in C# XML documentation?
I'm working on documenting some C# functions using XML comments and I want to reference a parameter with an alternative text instead of parameter name. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
/// <summary>
/// Calculates foo using <paramref name="theBarValue">β</paramref>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="theBarValue">The bar value (β).</param>
/// <returns>The calculated foo value.</returns>
public double Foo(double theBarValue)
{
return foo = theBarValue * 2;
}

In this example, I want the text "Calculates foo using β" to be displayed, with β as the link text pointing to the theBarValue parameter. However, it seems that the <paramref> tag doesn't support custom link text in this way. What I get from the above example is "Calculates foo using theBarValue." which is the same as if the XML was /// Calculates foo using <paramref name="theBarValue"/>.
Is there a way to achieve this in C# XML documentation, or any workaround to reference a parameter with custom link text?
Thanks in advance for your help.
PS: The provided example is just for illustration. My actual need is documenting some calculational functions where the parameters sometimes have long descriptive names. I want to use their symbols instead to make the descriptions easier to read.

Maybe with a <see cref="bar">foo</see> but at least Rider doesn't render that as a link. Didn't try to export an actual document from that, however.

Maybe also edit your example to showcase your actual problem with that (what you wrote in the PS section). I'd recommend to show the current situation and what you would like it to look like (but obviously doesn't work).

@Fildor Update the sample, hope it's clear now.

In C#, the  tag within XML documentation does not support custom link text. It can only reference a parameter by its name, and it always uses the parameter name as the link text. This means that you cannot directly achieve something like an HTML  tag where you display custom text (e.g., "β") while linking to a parameter.
However, you can manually reference the symbol in your description and clearly associate it with the parameter name. While this won't create a clickable link with custom text, it improves readability.
Just like this:
/// <summary>
/// Calculates foo using β (the value of <paramref name="theBarValue"/>).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="theBarValue">The bar value (β).</param>
/// <returns>The calculated foo value.</returns>
public double Foo(double theBarValue)
{
    return theBarValue * 2;
}


Which doesn't solve "My actual need is documenting some calculational functions where the parameters sometimes have long descriptive names. I want to use their symbols instead to make the descriptions easier to read." , unfortunately.

So it seems hard to understand your "actual need" and you may should edit your question to add detailed description. @Fildor

OP should. I am not the author of the question. And I already requested exactly that. Nevertheless, the quote is from the question. I am not saying "read more carefully" because sometimes questions get heavily edited after the first answers are posted. I just wanted to give you a heads-up. Other users won't hesitate to downvote for much less reason (or no reason whatsoever, unfortunately).

I have modified the contents of my answer to make it more consistent with the question. @Fildor
